# Change color of hostname in Fish shell prompt

Tags: shell, fish

I'm migrating to a new Mac, and I'm having trouble setting up my shell to match the old one.

Old:

[image]

New:

[image]

Notice the host color is different? I copied the entire `.config/fish` folder over to the computer, but it's still not working. The only difference I can think of is the version - 2.1.2, vs. 2.5.0. Here's my `fish_prompt.fish`:

```
function fish_prompt --description 'Write out the prompt'

    set -l last_status $status

    # Just calculate these once, to save a few cycles when displaying the prompt
    if not set -q __fish_prompt_hostname
        set -g __fish_prompt_hostname (hostname|cut -d . -f 1)
    end

    if not set -q __fish_prompt_normal
        set -g __fish_prompt_normal (set_color normal)
    end

    if not set -q -g __fish_classic_git_functions_defined
        set -g __fish_classic_git_functions_defined

        function __fish_repaint_user --on-variable fish_color_user --description "Event handler, repaint when fish_color_user changes"
            if status --is-interactive
                set -e __fish_prompt_user
                commandline -f repaint ^/dev/null
            end
        end

        function __fish_repaint_host --on-variable fish_color_host --description "Event handler, repaint when fish_color_host changes"
            if status --is-interactive
                set -e __fish_prompt_host
                commandline -f repaint ^/dev/null
            end
        end

        function __fish_repaint_status --on-variable fish_color_status --description "Event handler; repaint when fish_color_status changes"
            if status --is-interactive
                set -e __fish_prompt_status
                commandline -f repaint ^/dev/null
            end
        end
    end

    set -l delim '>'

    switch $USER

    case root

        if not set -q __fish_prompt_cwd
            if set -q fish_color_cwd_root
                set -g __fish_prompt_cwd (set_color $fish_color_cwd_root)
            else
                set -g __fish_prompt_cwd (set_color $fish_color_cwd)
            end
        end

    case '*'

        if not set -q __fish_prompt_cwd
            set -g __fish_prompt_cwd (set_color $fish_color_cwd)
        end

    end

    set -l prompt_status
    if test $last_status -ne 0
        if not set -q __fish_prompt_status
            set -g __fish_prompt_status (set_color $fish_color_status)
        end
        set prompt_status "$__fish_prompt_status [$last_status]$__fish_prompt_normal"
    end

    if not set -q __fish_prompt_user
        set -g __fish_prompt_user (set_color $fish_color_user)
    end
    if not set -q __fish_prompt_host
        set -g __fish_prompt_host (set_color $fish_color_host)
    end

    echo -n -s "$__fish_prompt_user" "$USER" "$__fish_prompt_normal" @ "$__fish_prompt_host" "$__fish_prompt_hostname" "$__fish_prompt_normal" ' ' "$__fish_prompt_cwd" (prompt_pwd) (__fish_git_prompt) "$__fish_prompt_normal" "$prompt_status" "$delim" ' '
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of fish color settings being stored as universal variables that are machine specific. If you look in your ~/.config/fish directory you'll see one or more files named fishd.* where the wildcard matches the mac address of the primary network interface of your computer. This is something many of us have argued should be changed. See this [issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1912). The solution is to simply copy the fish_color_* entries from the fishd file for your old system to your new one.

Comment: Accepting for now, though in looking at that file: `# This file is automatically generated by the fishd universal variable daemon.
# Do NOT edit it directly, your changes will be overwritten.`

Comment: You can safely ignore that warning in this case. It's basically telling you that if you edit the file by hand and then execute a `set -u` of the var you just hand edited your edit will be overwritten -- just as you would expect. It's a warning to keep people who don't know what they're doing from shooting themselves in the foot.